# Which is the better code behavior in my codes? How to change my codes?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Once I read a book says that create objects in the cycle is very low effective.Now I have to assembled a combination of objects in my cycle.How to change it to have more efficiency?

**My Model**

```
public class Student
{
    public int Age{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Sid{ get; set; }
}
```

**My circle code:to get all the student by sid**

```
var sidArr="1,2,3,4".split(',');
List<Student> studentes=new List<Student>();
for(int i=sidArr.count();i>=0;i--)
{
  Student student=new Student();
  student.Sid=i;
  var findStudent=student.GetStudentBySid(i);
  if(findStudent!=null)
 {
 student.Name=findStudent.Name;
 student.Age=findStudent.Age;
 }
 studentes.Add(student);
}
```

Should I put this code  `Student student=new Student();` outside the loop? Should I use design patterns if there are many sid to create many student?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement it like that (just don't do unnecessary opertaions in the loop: e.g. create new `Student` instance *if and only if* you *have to do* it)

```
var sidArr = "1,2,3,4".split(',');

List<Student> studentes = new List<Student>();

// 1. Count - 1: do not use Linq when you can use a simple property 
// 2. Count - 1: beware range check errors
// 3. foreach(int sid in sidArr) looks much better here
for(int i = sidArr.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
  // You should seach by sid, not by index i
  int sid = sidArr[i];

  var student = student.GetStudentBySid(sid);

  if (student == null) {
    // If student is not found, we have to create a new instance 
    student = new Student();

    student.Sid = isd; // <- do not forget to set the SID
    student.Name = findStudent.Name;
    student.Age = findStudent.Age;
  } 

  // Add student: either found or created one
  studentes.Add(student);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry Bychenko,In my situation,it seems I have to create the object in the loop.What about you?Do you use prototype design patterns to avoid creating recycle object?

Comment: .Net specially designed for creating and collecting many of short lived instances; that's why if you have just 4 (or 4000) Students only - create them. You'd probably want to avoid re-creating if the constructor is time consuming - e.g. you have to load values from database.

Answer (score 1):

> Once I read a book says that create objects in the cycle is very low effective.

You either missed the context or that book is trash.

> How to change it to have more efficiency?

You never EVER talk about efficiency without profiling your code. Trying to make code more efficient without knowing that the code is a performance problem in the whole picture is never a good idea.

Your code is so simple any attempt to optimize it will only increase the complexity of the code while not giving you any measurable performance gain.

> Should I put this code  `Student student=new Student();` outside the loop?

No, that will change meaning of the code.